# How do I add a System library to the Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

**How do I add a System library to the Android Studio?**

eclipse >

1. Adding the system library

   Properties - Java Build Path - Libraries - Add Library - User Library -  New - System library check - Done
2. Apply

   Preference - Java Build Path - Order and Export

**How to do this on Android Studio 1.2 ?**

Comment: you can add it in `build.gradle` file or paste library inside libs folder and refrence it inside `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way like Eclipse provide.
You have to write a script into root project's build.gradle
Here is mine(Mac env). It works with Android Studio 2.1.2 and Gradle 2.1.2

```
project(':YOUR_APP_PROJECT'){
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs.add('-Xbootclasspath/p'
                +':/Users/YOU/SYS_LIB/framework-classes-full-debug.jar'
                +':/Users/YOU/SYS_LIB/core-classes-full-debug.jar'                                     
            )
        }
    }
}
```

================UPDATE===================

```
project(project.path){
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            String sysLib = ":"+project.projectDir.path+"/sysLibs/"
            String frameworkClasses="framework-classes-full-debug.jar"

            options.compilerArgs.add('-Xbootclasspath/p'+sysLib+frameworkClasses')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Android Studio you need to Import as module.
if you have library project
1. File --> New --> Import Module--> give the library project path.
and add it module dependency

if you have library file
2. File --> Project Structure --> select the module "app" then go Dependencies tab click on Plus ( + ) you will see three option 
  1. Library dependency.
  2. file dependency.
  3. Module dependency.

Add whichever system Library you have in it.